# How to assign Categories and tags inside the TinyMCE Editor for each Image?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, tags

I am publishing Maths Solved paper on my website (Picture below), 
Each paper contains 25 questions which mean 25 maths Topics,
How can I assign Maths topic name as the category for each of the image,
The idea is when the user clicks on Topic Name for example 'Algebra' he should see all Algebra questions from different papers in a single page.
Please let me know how to do this. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you using custom post type?

Comment: Yes, Now I am thinking to add Custom Post Type for each question.

Comment: That would be plenty. Why not just used categories.